# Getting [ERROR] zip END header not found in Serenity BDD Maven project in IntelliJ IDE CE

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, automation, serenity-bdd

On running a test scenario I am getting this error in MAVEN automation project

Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] error reading /Users/userid/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/4.1.2/selenium-remote-driver-4.1.2.jar; zip file is empty

zip END header not found

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)

Tried running this several times and building the project still getting this

Comment: Looks like a corrupted dependency. Try deleting the "4.1.2" folder and running the build again. Maven should download a new copy of the dependency files.

Comment: @romanv-jb -Thanks I did delete the repository file this error is fixed  but i am getting this error where I am not able to generate Serenity report after successful run of scenario . Build is failing :  -  Failed to execute goal net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:3.2.1:aggregate (serenity-reports) on project digitalContent: Execution serenity-reports of goal net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:3.2.1:aggregate failed:Plugin net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:3.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: